# how to dynamically generate mailto: from AJAX with HTML

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have an XML document that contains email addresses and I want to read in those email addresses via AJAX then render them in HTML clickable links that (of course) allow me to send an email to that address.

JavaScript code stub:

```
emailobj = listings[i].getElementsByTagName("EMAIL")
document.getElementById("email").innerHTML = emailobj[0].firstChild.data
```

HTML code stub (I know this code below does not work -- but what does work the given above JavaScript)

```
<div id="email"></div>
```

For HTML, maybe something like

```
<a href="mailto:" + email></a>
```

The final result should be the email address rendered on the web page and clickable to send email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with just the following html:

```
<div id="email"></div>
```

You can modify the code you have to the following (given your emailobj is being populated like you want):

```
var emailobj = listings[i].getElementsByTagName("EMAIL");
var emailAddress = emailobj[0].firstChild.data;
var emailLink = document.createElement("a");

emailLink.innerHTML = emailAddress; 
emailLink.setAttribute("href", "mailto:" + emailAddress);
document.getElementById("email").appendChild(emailLink);
```

Comment: Impressive.  Very close.  I get myemail@yahoo.com as text then right next to it myemail@yahoo.com as a link.  It would work perfect if I could just get rid of the text and have just the myemail@yahoo.com link.

Comment: Disregard previous comment.  I figured out what was causing the issue.  Your solution worked perfectly! Thanks.